# Find the latest 3 records with the same status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I need to find the latest 3 records for each user that has a particular status on 'Fail'. At first it seems easy but I just can't seem to get it right.

So in a table of:

```
ID         Date            Status
1          2017-01-01     Fail
1          2017-01-02     Fail
1          2017-02-04     Fail
1          2015-03-21     Pass
1          2014-02-19     Fail
1          2016-10-23     Pass
2          2017-01-01     Fail
2          2017-01-02     Pass
2          2017-02-04     Fail
2          2016-10-23     Fail
```

I would expect ID 1 to be returned as the most recent 3 records are fails, but not ID 2, as they have a pass within their three fails. Each user may have any number of Pass and Fail records. There are thousands of different IDs

So far I've tried a CTE with ROW_NUMBER() to order the attempts but can't think of a way to ensure that the latest three results all have the same status of Fail.

Expected Results

```
ID Latest Fail Date    Count
1  2017-02-04          3
```

Comment: Show us your query attempt!

Comment: can you add expected result fot it

Comment: @jarlh the query attempt doesn't work so there's not much point in showing it - I have made several attempts so I'm not just looking for an easy answer be assured.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale I've edited the question to include expected results

Comment: @bhs i cant see date '2017-02-24 '  in input table ? can you re check both i/o

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale expected output changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
WITH cte
AS 
(

SELECT id,
       date,
       status,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) row
FROM #table


),cte2
AS
(

SELECT  id, max(date) as date, count(*) AS count
FROM cte
WHERE status = 'fail'
AND row <= 3
GROUP BY id
)

SELECT id,
       date AS latest_fail,
       count
FROM cte2
WHERE count = 3
```

Comment: Just testing this and I'm sure it is working ok - thanks :-)

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

Demo : [Here](http://rextester.com/SDZT49093)

```
with CTE as
(
 select *,ROW_NUMBER () over( partition by id order by date desc) rnk 
 from temp
 where Status ='Fail'
)
 select top 1 ID,max(DATE) as Latest_Fail_Date ,COUNT(rnk) as count 
 from CTE where rnk <=3
 group by ID
```

> Ouptut :

[image]

Comment: This is fine but there are thousands of IDs, each with their histories of Pass.Fails etc. I need a query to give me a list of all IDs matching the pattern. I've edited the question as this was not clear before.

Comment: @bhs I cant get what you want .? which pattenr ?ID is user ID ?

Comment: a .list of all IDs matching the pattern of three latest Fail records

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using `cross apply`:

```
select i.id
from (select distinct id from t) i cross apply
     (select sum(case when t.status = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as numFails
      from (select top 3 t.*
            from t
            where t.id = i.id
            order by date desc
           ) ti
      ) ti
where numFails = 3;
```

Note:  You probably have a table with all the ids.  If so, you an use that instead of the `select distinct` subquery.

Or, similarly:

```
select i.id
from (select distinct id from t) i cross apply
     (select top 3 t.*
      from t
      where t.id = i.id
      order by date desc
      ) ti
group by i.id
having min(ti.status) = 'Fail' and max(ti.status) = 'Fail' and
       count(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
declare @numOfTries int = 3;

with fails_nums as 
(
       select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by [Date] desc) as rn
       from #fails
)
select ID, max([Date]) [Date], count(*) as [count]
from fails_nums fn1
where fn1.rn <= @numOftries
group by ID
having count(case when [Status]='Fail' then [Status] end) = @numOfTries
```

[Example here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/706966/find-the-latest-3-records-with-the-same-status)

Comment: I like this as it's quite elegant and easy to read (and I've not used ALL before) but it doesn't work. If there is a single row with a fail that will be returned as well.